# Google Sheets scraping by clicking on a link

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to scrape product details from the below site
https://m.banggood.com/Mamibot-Smart-Dry-and-Wet-Mopping-Robot-with-GPS-Navigator-Planned-Clean-Route-p-1224893.html

For that I need to first click on the View More link and then get the description.

It is not possible to navigate to the link directly.

So, it is possible to click on the View More link through Google Sheets Script?

Comment: No, it is not possible to click using Google Script on another page.

Comment: Is there a way to execute the underlying JavaScript in that case?